# I want to force a certain keyword when creating a function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, keyword

For example,
all functions must include the _inline keyword.
If not, a build error should occur.

```
_inline int somefunction()
{
     return 0;
}

int somefunction2()
{
     return 0;
}

int main() 
{
     somefunction();
     somefunction2(); // build error!
}
```

This is to prevent certain functions from missing certain keywords due to human error.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the actual and underlying problem you want to solve? Why do you think adding e.g. `_inline` would solve that problem?

Comment: The reason for adding _inline is to prevent function calls from happening.
The keyword is not specified because in some cases other keywords such as volatile are used.

Comment: You can dig into libclang and write a custom code analyzer.

Comment: @ilikecat If you really want to prevent function calls from happening you could write macros instead. No idea why you want want to do that however, what's wrong with function calls?

Comment: If your company have specific requirements of functions, I would expect they use static analyzers on VCS commit/checkin to enforce what can be checked automatically, and then use code reviews to catch everything else. Is that not enough for your company?

Comment: because functions written in macros are poorly readable and difficult to debug.

Comment: It's possible to create something that does something like a static analyzer, but it doesn't currently exist, and I wanted to know if there is something like that in VS.

Comment: There is no inline check rule for .cpp  in Visual Studio.   You need to create it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that this is an xy-problem and you have no specific reason to inline all the functions because you didn't state one:

### Trust your compiler.

If the definition of the function is in the same translation unit as the callsite, the compiler will generally be able to inline the function. All common C++ compilers are very good at deciding wether it's actually a good idea to inline a function or not. Unless you have *very specific* requirements on why you need your function to be inlined, the compiler will probably make a better decision than you could make yourself.

**Note that unconditionally inlining all function calls is rarely a good idea. It will drastically increase binary size which then leads to many instruction cache misses, which will slow down your program.**

If the definition of the function is in another translation unit than the call site, no `inline` keyword (or `__always_inline__` or other compiler extensions) will make the compiler inline the function, because it does not see the definition. That is unless you enable link time optimization, but in that case you can again trust your compiler to make a good decision.